# How to execute a procedure when a view column is changed?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, view, triggers

I have a view that is something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW BUILDS_VIEW AS
SELECT   BUILD_LIST.BUILD_ID,
         BUILDSTATUS_LIST.RELEASE_FLAG
FROM     BUILD_LIST,
         BUILDSTATUS_LIST
WHERE    BUILD_LIST.BUILDSTATUS = BUILDSTATUS_LIST.BUILDSTATUS;
```

BUILDSTATUS_LIST example:

```
BUILDSTATUS RELEASE_FLAG
----------- ------------
    -1           N      
     0           N      
     1           N      
     2           Y      
     3           Y      
     4           Y
```

BUILD_LIST example:

```
BUILD_ID BUILDSTATUS
-------- -----------
  12345       3     
  23456       0     
  34567       1
```

I want to execute a stored procedure `processBuildReleaseChange(BUILD_ID)` when there is a change to the `RELEASE_FLAG` column

There are many more `BUILDSTATUS`s than that and they are changed often, so I want to only execute the procedure when the view is changed

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to know when the value returned by a view changes rather than when the value stored in a table changes?  If the view is this simple, it's easy enough to use a trigger on the table (assuming the procedure doesn't need to read or write to the `build_list` table).  If the view is performing some more complex calculations where the data comes from many different tables, life is much more complicated.

Comment: @JustinCave My view is much more complicated than that.. The release flag column data is actually pulled from another view that analyses a few tables

Comment: OK.  Can the view be converted into a materialized view (ideally probably fast-refreshable)?

Comment: @JustinCave I updated my description to be a little more "descriptive" (I was wrong about pulling the column from another view, that's a whole other issue) I'm not sure what a materialized fast-refreshable view is... this is my first endeavor with views

Comment: It sounds like you're doing some kind of build/release automation. Is there an earlier process you can capture to trigger the call to the SP? Hopefully you can gather that you can't build an AFTER trigger on a view but you can on a table. Does it need to be instantaneous? Because another option is to run a scheduled job (say every 3 minutes) that just checks the view and runs the SP if required.

Comment: If this is roughly similar to the actual level of complexity, a row-level trigger on `build_list` could look at changes to the `buildstatus` column and do a lookup against `buildstatus_list` to see whether the `release_flag` changed and call the procedure assuming the procedure doesn't need to read from or modify the `build_list` table.  I would expect that you would be better off not using a trigger, though, and embedding this logic in whatever piece of code implements status changes.

Comment: @JustinCave there are too many places in our code that make changes to  `build_list.buildstatus` to maintain. I didn't realize I could do lookups in triggers, that could work

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I didn't think about scheduled tasks, that could also work thank you